# Javascript nested object access speed

Tags: javascript

I have been struggling to understand why accessing nested objects are faster.

Here we have a small benchmark.

```
  var nested1 = {level1: null};
  var nested2 = {level1: {level2: null}};
  var nested3 = {level1: {level2: {level3: null}}};
  var nested4 = {level1: {level2: {level3: {level4: null}}}};
```

After defining our test objects we benchmark the access results.

```
nested1.level1;
```

is 14% slower than

```
nested4.level1.level2.level3.level4;
```

But how it is possible?
Here is the [jsPerf](https://jsperf.com/accessing-nested-objects)

This question is not related with caching deeply nested variables. I am just trying to understand what makes deep references faster on some browsers.

Comment: seems it cache the parent objects

Comment: I see a 0.06% difference between fastest (1,3,4) and slowest (2) - probably browser dependant - probably chrome sux :p

Comment: I ran that test on IE11 and `nested1` was heaps quicker than `nested4`. Seems like it is up to js engine and internals.

Comment: Chrome has a huge difference between 1 and 4. It must have a reason. I dont want to say Chrome sux but not IE :)

Comment: My guess is that [you were fooled by the optimiser](http://mrale.ph/talks/goto2015/#/71) which [hoisted the property accesses out of the benchmark loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop-invariant_code_motion) - only for long chains but not a single property access (where it wouldn't make much difference).